# 2 Intersection Lines

Tags: c++, geometry, linear-algebra

i have this code to find the status of 2 lines there are 3 cases:

1- the lines are intersect in one point

2- they are parallel

3- special case of parallel they are identical[same line]

and here is my code but i still can't understand this two parts of code

```
if(!D && (Dx || Dy))
    puts("NONE"); // the lines are parallel
if(!D && !Dx && !Dy)
    puts("LINE"); // they are the same lime
```

why when the determinater is zero and `dx = 0` or `dy = 0` then they are parallel and when `d = 0` and `dx = 0` and `dy = 0` then they are the same line
i know when determinater equal to zero then there is no unique solution but can't understand the part of `!DX` and `!DY` and `DX || DY`

Here is the full code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct point{
    int x , y;
};

struct segment{
    point s , e;
};

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d" , &n);
    puts("INTERSECTING LINES OUTPUT");
    while(n--){
        segment a , b;
        scanf("%d%d%d%d" , &a.s.x , &a.s.y , &a.e.x , &a.e.y);
        scanf("%d%d%d%d" , &b.s.x , &b.s.y , &b.e.x , &b.e.y);
        double a1 , b1 , c1 , a2 , b2 , c2 , D , Dx , Dy;
        a1 = a.e.y - a.s.y;
        b1 = a.s.x - a.e.x;
        c1 = a1 * (a.s.x) + b1 * (a.s.y);

        a2 = b.e.y - b.s.y;
        b2 = b.s.x - b.e.x;
        c2 = a2 * (b.s.x) + b2 * (b.s.y);

        D = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;
        Dx = c1 * b2 - c2 * b1;
        Dy = a1 * c2 - a2 * c1;

        if(!D && (Dx || Dy))
            puts("NONE"); // the lines are parallel
        if(!D && !Dx && !Dy)
            puts("LINE"); // they are the same line
        else printf("POINT %.2f %.2f\n" , (double)Dx / D , (double) Dy / D);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This is just bad programming to write `if(x)` when `x` is a `double`. It should be `if(x!=0.0)` in order to make it clear.

Comment: `here is my code but i still can't understand this two parts of code`  so you do not understand your own code? It happens to best of us with older code that is what comments are for... Also instead of `!D` use `fabs(D)<1e-6` or similar ... probability a `double` will be exactly zero is very low...

Comment: Is this an attempted solution of some on-line judged programming competition? That would explain the integer type of the structs members and inputs (a general solution would require `double`s) and the overconfident C I/O part. If that is the case, variables `D`, `Dx` and `Dy` might also be of integer type (maybe `long long int`), leading to precise calculations (and making sense of the casts in `printf`, too).

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this, roughly speaking, is that when D==0 and Dx==0 and Dy==0, then the "coordinates of the intersection point" Dx/D and Dy/D are indeterminate forms 0/0 which could be any number. That means that the lines intersect in a whole bunch of points, which is only possible if they are the same line.

On the other hand, if D==0 and Dx!=0 or Dy!=0 (or both), then the value of Dx/D or Dy/D (or both) is infinity. In other words, the lines intersect at infinity (only), which is another way of saying that the lines are parallel and not coincident.

Testing if(D) for a double is a bad idea, for a couple of reasons. 1) It's not clear. Understanding that expression requires some fairly detailed knowledge of type conversions in the language that frankly not every programmer has. 2) Rounding errors and other numerical instability issues could interfere with the calculation and instead of D==0 you have some tiny D not equal to 0. Then !D is considered true, even though it should be false without the rounding error. Instead you should compare whether abs(D) < some tolerance which is slightly bigger than 0.

Finally your program is vulnerable to overflow issues: if the two lines are close in slope, but otherwise completely reasonable, the intersection point may be extremely large. This is a situation that makes sense in a purely mathematical context, but not so much sense on a computer. Instead, a better question to ask would be whether the intersection lies within the line segments defined by the points. There is a discussion of that problem on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line).

Answer (score 0):

The feedback that worries about floating point arithmetic is on point (Ha!). Since the input is integral, though, I might suggest doing the math with integer types.

The questions you are asking boil down to seeing if two fractions are equivalent. I suggest the following helper class:

```
struct ratio {
    int dx;
    int dy;

    ratio(int dxIn, int dyIn) :
        dx(dxIn), dy(dyIn) {
    }

    bool isEquivalent(ratio rhs) const {
        if ((dx == 0 && dy == 0) || (rhs.dx == 0 && rhs.dy == 0))
            return (dx == 0 && dy == 0) && (rhs.dx == 0 && rhs.dy == 0);
        return dx * rhs.dy == dy * rhs.dx;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Each line segment is converted into `(a,b,c)` coordinates for the extended line which form the line equation `a*x+b*y+c=0`. What you need to know, is that the vector `(a,b)` is orthogonal to the line.

The quantity `D = a1*b2 - a2*b1` is the cross product between the two orthogonal vectors. As you know the cross product of two parallel vectors is `0`. So if that is true, the two lines are either coincident or parallel.

The intersection point is defined as `(Dx/D,Dy/D)` where `Dx=b1*c2-b2*c1` and `Dy=a2*c1-a1*c2`, so when all equals zero `Dx=Dy=D=0` the intersection point is undefined, meaning the lines are coincident. Otherwise if only `D=0` the intersection point is at infinity and the lines are parallel.

The rest is just typical <strike>confusing</strike> `C` syntax.